# AWS Glue Job-bookmark not working when sending data from dynamodb to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am trying to send data from dynamodb to s3 using AWS Glue. In the documentation, it is mentioned that job bookmark will keep a state of past jobs hence will only transfer new data into s3. But its not working when I am sending data to s3. It's copying whole dynamodb table to s3 instead of copying only newly added data. I need to use the SQL functionality of Athena. How do I rectify it?

Comment: its not enabled by default, you enabled it? can you paste `aws glue get-job --job-name my-glue-job --generate-cli-skeleton > my_glue_job.json` we need to check `--job-bookmark-option`

Comment: @BaluVyamajala I have enabled it. I looked on forums and people have mentioned that it only works from s3 to s3 not from dynamodb to s3.

Answer (score 0):

Please be advised that AWS Glue job bookmark feature works for S3 and JDBC datasources only as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html)